# VS2010 throws exception while opening project

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2010

When I try opening a project I get an exception saying Web application is configured to use IIS.

Error  : The Web Application Project EntityServices is configured to use IIS. To access local IIS Web sites, you must install the following IIS components:

```
  IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility
```

In addition, you must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator account.

NOTE - I have already installed IIS 7. My box is a x64 bit Windows 7 box.

Comment: Did you you read the message?

Comment: Just follow the message -- both parts -- and things will work (IIS7 has many parts with fine grained control of what is installed, just selecting IIS will not install all the bits VS needs).

Comment: Please don't invent new tags, we have more than enough already.

Comment: I agree with the responders that the error's suggestion is straightforward enough, but I think the real frustration is wondering why VS 2010 and Windows 7/2008 need a compatibility protocol circa 2003 to communicate.  I think Prashant is asking whether there is a more modern way of getting it to work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to *Control Panel*, *Programs and Features*, *Turn Windows Features On or Off*, and enable IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed IIS6 Metabase support?  It is a seperate install from IIS7, although in the same area.

Turn Windows Features ON and OFF -> IIS Services-> Web Management Tools -> IIS Management Compatibility and check IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration Compatibility

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me when I had reconfigured the TCP Port on IIS to port 81.  I was running TCPTrace, capturing traffic on port 80 and forwarding it to IIS at port 81.

After a reboot, I had to reconfigure IIS' TCP Port to 80 and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error the solution is that you should open with notepad (web project)it's csproj file and remove this tag

```
<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to turn on asp.net :
controlpanel- Turn Windows Features ON and OFF -> IIS Services-> www- > application Dewvelopment features check the asp.net on

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Same error)
i solved my problem with following steps. 
1-)open your project file with a text editor.
2-)find  "USEIIS" tag and replace its value with "False". save and exit. 
3-)reopen your project file with visual studio